# Python Protocol for Building a `pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, protocols

Hello SO and community!

Guess, my question somewhat resonates with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798903/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-protocol-for-a-pandas-dataframe).

However, trust the below task is a little bit different from that referenced above, namely to extract, transform, load data utilizing `pandas.DataFrame`, and I am stuck implementing `Protocol` for the purpose.

The code is below:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import re
import requests
from functools import cache
from typing import Protocol
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pandas import DataFrame


@cache
def extract_can_from_url(url: str, **kwargs) -> DataFrame:
    '''
    Returns DataFrame from downloaded zip file from url
    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str
        url to download from.
    **kwargs : TYPE
        additional arguments to pass to pd.read_csv().
    Returns
    -------
    DataFrame
    '''
    name = url.split('/')[-1]
    if os.path.exists(name):
        with ZipFile(name, 'r').open(name.replace('-eng.zip', '.csv')) as f:
            return pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs)
    else:
        r = requests.get(url)
        with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content)).open(name.replace('-eng.zip', '.csv')) as f:
            return pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs)


class ETL(Protocol):
    # =============================================================================
    # Maybe Using these items for dataclass:
    # url: str
    # meta: kwargs(default_factory=dict)
    # =============================================================================
    def __init__(self, url: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        return None

    def download(self) -> DataFrame:
        return DataFrame

    def retrieve_series_ids(self) -> list[str]:
        return list[str]

    def transform(self) -> DataFrame:
        return DataFrame

    def sum_up_series_ids(self) -> DataFrame:
        return DataFrame


class ETLCanadaFixedAssets(ETL):
    def __init__(self, url: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.url = url
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @cache
    def download(self) -> DataFrame:
        self.df = extract_can_from_url(URL, index_col=0, usecols=range(14))
        return self.df

    def retrieve_series_ids(self) -> list[str]:
        # =========================================================================
        # Columns Specific to URL below, might be altered
        # =========================================================================
        self._columns = {
            "Prices": 0,
            "Industry": 1,
            "Flows and stocks": 2,
            "VECTOR": 3,
        }
        self.df_cut = self.df.loc[:, tuple(self._columns)]
        _q = (self.df_cut.iloc[:, 0].str.contains('2012 constant prices')) & \
            (self.df_cut.iloc[:, 1].str.contains('manufacturing', flags=re.IGNORECASE)) & \
            (self.df_cut.iloc[:, 2] == 'Linear end-year net stock')
        self.df_cut = self.df_cut[_q]
        self.series_ids = sorted(set(self.df_cut.iloc[:, -1]))
        return self.series_ids

    def transform(self) -> DataFrame:
        # =========================================================================
        # Columns Specific to URL below, might be altered
        # =========================================================================
        self._columns = {
            "VECTOR": 0,
            "VALUE": 1,
        }
        self.df = self.df.loc[:, tuple(self._columns)]
        self.df = self.df[self.df.iloc[:, 0].isin(self.series_ids)]
        return self.df

    def sum_up_series_ids(self) -> DataFrame:
        self.df = pd.concat(
            [
                self.df[self.df.iloc[:, 0] == series_id].iloc[:, [1]]
                for series_id in self.series_ids
            ],
            axis=1
        )
        self.df.columns = self.series_ids
        self.df['sum'] = self.df.sum(axis=1)
        return self.df.iloc[:, [-1]]
```

***UPD***

Instantiating the class `ETLCanadaFixedAssets`

```
df = ETLCanadaFixedAssets(URL, index_col=0, usecols=range(14)).download().retrieve_series_ids().transform().sum_up_series_ids()
```

returns an error, however, expected:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'retrieve_series_ids'
```

Please can anyone provide a guidance for how to put these things together (namely how to retrieve the `DataFrame` which might have been retrieved otherwise using the procedural approach by calling the functions within the last `class` as they appear within the latter) and point at those mistakes which were made above?

Probably, there is another way to do this elegantly using injection.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you `return self.df` in your `__init__` method? `__init__` should always `return None`, preferably implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

All the functions of ETLCanadaFixedAssets and ETL classes should return self. This will allow you to call the functions of the class on the return value of the functions, so you can chain them together. You could add one more function that retrieves the encapsulated dataframe but that will always be called last, as the moment you call this function you cannot chain other functions any more. What you are trying to build is called fluent API you may read more about it [here](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/fluentinterface/#:%7E:text=Fluent%20Interface%20pattern%20provides%20easily%20readable%20flowing%20interface%20to%20code.&text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20a%20fluent,%2Dspecific%20language%20(DSL).)

For example:

```py
class ETL(Protocol):
    def download(self) -> ETL:
        ...

    def retrieve_series_ids(self) -> ETL:
        ...

    def transform(self) -> ETL:
        ...

    def sum_up_series_ids(self) -> ETL:
        ...

    @property
    def dataframe(self) -> DataFrame:
        ...
```

Note you will need the following import line to be able to use the class annotation inside the class definition

`from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).